# Match game using CSS3 checking tiles

Tags: html, css, webkit

Am developing a game using HTML5 and CSS3.

I have a bunch of divs that have CSS3 animations attached to them on hover events. The game is a basic match the tiles/cars game. This is -webkit- only so runs best in Chrome.

Here is a preview : http://tinyurl.com/3ry2bgn

I want to attach game logic but am stumped on what approach to take.

Can I just attach additional ids to the DIVs and use JavaScript to just check that?

How can I make the animations animated onClick events? Or better on tap events for the iPad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control CSS3 animations via Javascript, the best thing to do generally is to place the animation style in a class, and then add that class in the onClick event handler.

You can use animation events to detected the end of the animation and remove the class, so that the animation relaunches on subsequent events, or you could just check in each onClick event if the class has already been added, and then if it has, remove it before reading it.

Although you are using a Webkit-based browser, the [Mozilla Developer Reference CSS Animations Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_animations) is still an excellent reference -- just replace the -moz- vendor prefix with -webkit- ;-)

Comment: Thanks that gives me some ideas about approaching this. Do you happen to have any links to doing that, i.e. creating classes for animation.

Am thinking I might use jQuery to do this... though I don't know the effect on performance then... thanks!

Comment: if you're still looking for info, try http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg2/